# Qt Threading Ownership

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have a Qt Application which connects to X physical devices via bluetooth and does some monitoring. I want to have a kind of ThreadOverseer class which creates a Thread for each device to be monitored as needed and can act upon messages from each device Thread. I have broken my coding style down to this minimal example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>



class DeviceThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DeviceThread(){}

    void startThread(){this->start(QThread::NormalPriority);}
    void stopThread(){
        m_ping_timer->stop();
        this->quit();
        if (!this->wait(3000)) { this->terminate(); }
    }

    void init(int deviceId){m_deviceId = deviceId;
                           this->moveToThread(this);}

    void run(){
        m_ping_timer = new QTimer(this);
        m_ping_timer->setInterval(5000);
        connect(m_ping_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onPing()));
        m_ping_timer->start();

        this->exec();
    }
private slots:
    void onPing(){
        emit newData(m_deviceId);
    }

signals:
    void newData(int deviceId);
private:
    int m_deviceId;
    QTimer* m_ping_timer;
};

class ThreadOverseer : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ThreadOverseer(){}
    void startThread(){
        this->start(QThread::NormalPriority);
    }
    void stopThread(){
        foreach(int deviceId, m_device_threads.keys())
        {
            DeviceThread* thread = m_device_threads.value(deviceId, nullptr);
            if(thread){
                thread->stopThread();
                delete thread;
                thread = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        foreach(int deviceId, m_deviceIds)
        {
             DeviceThread* dthread = new DeviceThread();
             dthread->init(deviceId);
             connect(dthread, SIGNAL(newData(int)), this, SLOT(onNewDeviceData(int)));
             dthread->startThread();
             m_device_threads.insert(deviceId, dthread);

        }
        this->exec();
    }

    void init(QList<int> deviceIds)
    {
        m_deviceIds = deviceIds;
        this->moveToThread(this);
    }

public slots:
    void onNewDeviceData(int deviceId){
        qDebug() <<  "OVERSEER GOT NEW PING FROM "<< deviceId;
    }

private:
    QList<int> m_deviceIds;
    QMap<int, DeviceThread*> m_device_threads;

};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList<int> deviceIds;
    deviceIds << 4 << 8 << 42;

    ThreadOverseer* overseer = new ThreadOverseer();
    overseer->init(deviceIds);
    overseer->startThread();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have read the Qt documentation multiple times. It looks like in cases that where you want to paralize one-shot type tasks you create a QObject which does the stuff needed and move it to a QThread (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details).
The docs also mention in case that if I want to send data from the ThreadOverseer to slots in my deviceThreads the worker-object approach is not the best, and subclassing is also an option. So I created the above example.

However this this->moveToThread(this) inside the thread seems really dirty to me. Is there a better way to do this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you inherit workers from `QThread` in the first place? Instead of just moving them to a new thread after creation. I'm wondering if there's a specific need for that or if that's just how you have tried it so far. I agree moving a thread to itself isn't right. You also don't need a QTimer here, a QBasicTimer and listening to QEvent::TimerEvent would be cleaner. But I digress.

Comment: Also if you're not tied to QThread in particular (pun intended!) another approach might be something like [QConcurrent::run()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) from your `ThreadOverseer` manager class. You could use that to fire pings to different hosts on a schedule and check the responses from the returned `QFuture` events (also see [QFutureWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html)). It may be a more concise and centralized approach, depending on your needs. The actual "ping" functions would be simpler also.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by “dirty” but moveToThread() is considered a completely viable mechanism in QtLand, assuming you really need threads at the application level.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html discusses alternatives. I see nothing wrong with your implementation, though.

Comment: Except one typically uses `moveToThread()` from outside the `QThread` in question. IMHO `this->moveToThread(this)` doesn't seem right.